# Modernizr - is it more than just feature detection

Tags: modernizr

I'm not sure I get the value of using Modernizr. I read, and reread their site. What is the value in having a script that performs tests to see if a browser has the ability to have the latest html5/css3 features?  Does it actually PROVIDE the feature if the browser doesn't natively do it? Seems like a lot of work to do what jQuery can pretty much already do.

Answer (score 0):

It does provide some features through polyfills

> "The name “Modernizr” might throw you for a second, we’ll admit. The
>   library does allow you to use the new HTML5 sectioning elements in IE,
>   but aside from that, it doesn’t modernize any other features. The name
>   Modernizr actually stems from the goal of modernizing our development
>   practices (and ourselves)."

http://modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that it's still only a feature detection script, but if it detects that the browser doesn't have that feature, I can take the time to read and memorize the features of any of the 300 polyfills at https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills to do, then implement those scripts.  Still seems a like quite a bit of work to get these new features (most of which already seem already doable with jquery) to be backwards compatible.

Comment: It's mainly feature detection apart from HTML5Shiv which it includes. It's all outlined on that page.